# Using replicate over for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, replicate

I want to make a simulation 10000 times on the difference between load and demand. I need the proportion of negative differences over all simulation. I used the for loop below, but this is not performant for large simulations as it requires me to calculate everything by hand later on.

How can I do the same with replicate? What are the benefits of using replicate over for loop?

```
 for(i in 1:10){
 load<-rnorm(10,8,2)
 demand<-c(6,7,6,5,6,7,8,7,6,5)
 diff<-load-demand
 res<-sum(diff<0) / 10# sum the negative differences
 print(res)
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big disadvantage of using a for-loop, is that you don't automatically store everything in an object. `replicate()` does that for you.

Another tip: keep everything that doesn't change out of the loop (like the definition of `demand`)

How to do what you describe using `replicate()`:

```
nsim <- 10000
demand <- c(6,7,6,5,6,7,8,7,6,5)
res <- replicate(nsim,{
  load <- rnorm(10,8,2)
  diff <- load - demand
  return(sum(diff < 0))
})
res <- sum(res) / nsim
```

The `return()` function isn't necessary (a code block returns the last line it executes), but I add it so you see immediately what's going to be stored in `res`.

But you actually don't need a loop to do this (given you described what you want accurately). You can just use vectorization and recycling to do this:

```
nsim <- 10000
demand <- c(6,7,6,5,6,7,8,7,6,5)
load <- rnorm(10*nsim, 8, 2)
diff <- load - demand
res <- sum(diff < 0) / nsim
```

`replicate` or a `for` loop actually only make sense if you want to keep the results for each simulation. As you're only interested in the overall result, the second code block will be more performant and R-like.

Comment: Great! And I suppose is much faster than looping? If you need to do few ten thousand simulations the looping is quite time consuming

Comment: It's really a lot faster than looping for sure. But that's mainly due to the fact that `replicate` takes care of the creation of the result vector. Under the hood `replicate` is also a (very optimized) loop.

Comment: Something is not working right. I need to sum just the occurrences when the diff is negative. So in 5 iterations i need to have let say: 0,3,2,3,1 cases when the diff if negative than sum it up and divide it with 5 so 9/5 is 1.8

Comment: @kelamahim then you should describe your problem correctly. I did what you said in your opening post: sum the negative differences and divide by the number of simulations. What you ask now is proportion of negative differences over all simulations.

Comment: Is it possible to save the iterations of replicate? I want to plot the res divided  by the number of iterations

Comment: @kelamahim If you have `nsim` iterations and `res` is your result, then `res/seq_len(nsim)` will do the job if you want to divide every result by the iteration number. If you want to divide by the total number of iterations, then the answer is in the post above: `res/nsim`